# Does typedefing a struct re-introduce it every time it is used?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test{
  int a;
} my_test;

int main(){
 my_test t;
 return 0;
}
```

Is the above code snippet equal to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test{
  int a;
} my_test;

int main(){
 struct test{
  int a;
 } t;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @stark Sorry i'm not following.

Comment: You are defining a type and a struct both named test.  They are different things.

Comment: I've made a modification to make it more clear.

Comment: No. You can easily test this by trying to pass one type as a function argument when the other is expected.

Comment: The `struct test` with file scope and the `struct test` with block scope (in `main`) are different types. The declaration with file scope is hidden by the declaration with block scope until the end of the block.

Comment: @IanAbbott i know the scopes are different, i'm saying does typedefing it like above reintroduce it every time it is used? i.e it's like copy pasting the `struct` every time? isn't that what typedef does, an alias?

Comment: @Dan Try copy and pasting the same `struct test` definition twice at the same scope level and see what happens. (Hint: it won't compile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test{
  int a;
} my_test;

int main(){
 my_test t;
 return 0;
}
```

is equivalent to

(B)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test{
  int a;
} my_test;

int main(){
 struct test t;
 return 0;
}
```

but it is **not** equivalent to

(C)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test{
  int a;
} my_test;

int main(){
 struct test{
  int a;
 } t;
 return 0;
}
```

(C) Defines a different `struct test` at block scope within `main` that overrides the existing definition of `struct test` with file scope until the end of the block.

In (D)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
  int a;
};

typedef struct test my_test;

int main(){
 struct test{
  int a;
 } t;
 typedef struct test this_test;
 this_test u;
 my_test s;
 return 0;
}
```

the variables `t` and `u` have the same type as each other because `struct test` and `this_test` are the same type defined at block scope in `main`, but `s` has a different type because `my_test` is the same type as the `struct test` defined at file scope.

In (E)

```
struct {
   int a;
} a;

struct {
   int a;
} b;

typedef struct {
   int a;
} my_type;

my_type c;
my_type d;
```

the variables `a`, `b` and `c` all have different (anonymous structure) types, but `c` has the same type as `d`. For `c` and `d` the anonymous structure type used to define the type aliased by `my_type` has been pinned down by the `typedef` into something that can be referred to elsewhere.

Comment: Like I said, i know the scopes are different and I know copying it to the same scope won't compile. i'm saying when compiler is compiling the second code with a typedef, does it re intrude the same `strcut` in every scope all over again, like my example? i.e compiler sees `my_test` which is an alias and just replaces the entire  struct definition with `my_test` in the new scope?

Comment: @Dan In (B), `struct test` and `my_test` are the same type and can be used interchangeably, so nothing is "reintroduced".

Comment: I'm talking about (A) tho. compiler sees `my_test t;` and "copy pastes" `struct test{
  int a;
}`? since that's what it's referring to?

Comment: There is no "copy pasting". They just name the same type.

Comment: Exactly so since they name the same type, does it mean `test` is being reintroduced  in the new scope all over again, `similar` to copy pasting it (not saying it actually gets copy pasted`.

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion raised by the assumption `typedef` is handled by the preprocessor or is handled similarly by the compiler?

Comment: @JardelLucca `typedef` is not handled by the preprocessor.

Comment: i know its not handled by the preprocessor, but is it "similar" to just using a `#define` here? is the struct definition being reintroduced in every scope when `my_test` is used?

Comment: @Dan the `struct test` is only defined (or rather is only "completely defined") once. It is possible to "incompletely define" a type and "completely define" the same type later. Regardless, after `typedef struct test my_test`, `struct test` and `my_test` refer to the same underlying type which may or may not be completely defined at some point in the translation unit. But once `struct test` is "completely defined", `my_test` becomes "completely defined" at the same point. (I am ignoring the overriding of `struct test` and/or `my_test` within an enclosed block scope for the sake of clarity.)

Comment: @Dan: Re “a typedef, does it re intrude the same `strcut` in every scope all over again…”: A `typedef` provides a name for a particular type. It is a name for the type, not a name for the code that defines a type. `typedef struct test{
  int a;
} my_test;` defines a `struct` type and makes `my_test` a name for that type. Later, inside `main`, `my_test` is known to be that type. It is that type, and it does not behave as if `struct test` were declared again.

Comment: @Dan:  The rules for `struct` declarations say that if a `struct` declaration declares members, the `struct` declaration declares a new type, unlikely simply writing `struct test` without member declarations inside `{` and `}`. Using the `typedef` name does not redo a declaration.